# Splitting a List Based on a Substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100', '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100', '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']
```

I want to split this list into multiple lists so that each sublist will have the substring "(Reg)" appear once:

```
[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'],
['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'],
['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'],
['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'],
['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

I've tried joining the list with a delimiter and splitting it by (Reg), but that didn't work. How can I split the list into a nested list like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly different (optimized) version of WVO's answer:

```
splitted = []

for item in l:
    if '(Reg)' in item:
        splitted.append([])
    splitted[-1].append(item)

#[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'], ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'], 
# ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'], ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'], 
# ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'], 
# ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Comment: Very neat. I would never have thought of this logic

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with regular expressions:

```
import itertools
import re
s = ['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100', '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100', '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']
new_data = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\d+\(', x)))]
final_data = [new_data[i]+new_data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'], 
 ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'], 
 ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'], 
 ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'], 
 ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'], 
 ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way, though not necessarily optimal:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = ['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100',
       '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100',
       '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']

indices = [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if '(Reg)' in j]
lst_new = [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip_longest(indices, indices[1:])]

# [['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'],
#  ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'],
#  ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'],
#  ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
#  ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'],
#  ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's my take with super-simple standard list comprehensions (very similar to @jp_data_analysis's answer):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d = ['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100', '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100', '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']
>>> idx = filter(lambda i: d[i].endswith("(Reg)"), range(len(d))) + [len(d)]
>>> idx
[0, 5, 9, 13, 18, 23, 28]
>>> res = [d[idx[i-1]:idx[i]] for i in range(1,len(idx))]
>>> pprint(res)
[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'],
 ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'],
 ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'],
 ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
 ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'],
 ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Explanation: `idx` holds the indices of every element ending in `(Reg)` (including the list length as the final element). Then the list `res` is defined via intervals between those elements.

**On a philosophical note**: every time you face a problem like this, ask yourself: how did I get here? Why do I need to deal with some super-fragile implicit-string-format-rules instead of a real data structure? One that takes intervals and data hierarchy into account? One that enforces limitations by design and allows for simple querying? <sub>Find someone to blame and rant about them on Twitter :)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `for` loop for this and use two lists: one of the lists we use to build the current row, and the other lists stores all rows we currently have. Like:

```
rows = []
row = []
for word in data:
    if '(Reg)' in word:
        rows.append(row)
        row = []
    row.append(word)
rows.append(row)
```

with `data` the initial list of strings.

There is a problem with this however: it will first add an empty row (given the first element has `(Reg)` in it. We can prevent this by only adding non-empty `row`s, like:

```
rows = []
row = []
for word in data:
    if '(Reg)' in word:
        if row:
            rows.append(row)
        row = []
    row.append(word)
if row:
    rows.append(row)
```

We can generalize the above into a dedicated function:

```
split_at(data, predicate, with_empty=False):
    rows = []
    row = []
    for word in data:
        if predicate(word):
            if with_empty or row:
                rows.append(row)
            row = []
        row.append(word)
    if with_empty or row:
        rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

We can then call it like:

```
split_at(our_list, lambda x: '(Reg)' in x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
lst = ['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100', '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100', '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']
from itertools import groupby
[a+b for a,b in zip(*([iter(list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x:'Reg' in x))]*2))]
```

Output:

```
[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'],
 ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'],
 ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'],
 ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'],
 ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'],
 ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Comment: I don't think you need `iter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100', '2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100',
       '3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98', '4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100',
       '5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100', '6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']

grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x.endswith('(Reg)'))]

result = [x + y for x, y in zip(grouped[0::2], grouped[1::2])]

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[['1(Reg)', '100', '103', '102', '100'], ['2(Reg)', '98', '101', '100'], ['3(Reg)', '96', '99', '98'], ['4(Reg)', '100', '100', '100', '100'], ['5(Reg)', '98', '99', '99', '100'], ['6(Reg)', '99.47', '99.86', '99.67', '100']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way with no libraries. It is a list comprehension built off of DYZ's answer:

```
w = []
[w.append([e]) if '(Reg)' in e else w[-1].append(e) for e in data]
```